# FOSUser The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

My entity is :

```
<?php

namespace MainBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as lat_users;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="lat_users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends lat_users
{
    // ...
}
```

and my config.yml

```html
...
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MainBundle\Entity\lat_users
    from_email:
    
    ...
```

and it'says :

> The autoloader expected class "MainBundle\Entity\lat_users" to be defined in file "/var/www/intranet/vendor/composer/../../src/MainBundle/Entity/lat_users.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Idon't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `MainBundle\Entity\User` at config, as `lat_users` is the table name not entity name. your entity name is `User`, so :

```html
...
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MainBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:

    ...
```

Also, just as a best practice always use **Singular CamelCase** for class names and aliases in PHP:

replace:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as lat_users;

// ...

class User extends lat_users
```

by

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as LatUser;

// ...

class User extends LatUser
```